# Store list of images in django model

Tags: python, arrays, django, model, imagefield

I am building a Django data model and I want to be able to store an array of ImageFields.
Is it possible?

```
mainimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', null = True)
images = models.??
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Create another model to images and have foreignkey with your model.

```
def YourModel(models.Model):
    #your fields

def ImageModel(models.Model):
    mainimage = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', null = True)
    image = models.ForeignKey(YourModel, ...)
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use the ManyToMany relationship to link your model with an image model. This is the way to aggregate ImageField as django does not have aggregate model field

```
def YourModel(models.Model):
    images = ManyToManyField(ImageModel)
    ...

def ImageModel(models.Model):
    img = ImageField()
    name ...
```

Maybe you need something more performant (this could lead to lots of horrible joins)